# How to have a generic solution to parse an unknown class to Json in scalaJs

Tags: angularjs, json, scala, scala.js, upickle

I'm using ScalaJs angular and Upickle and I try to create a filter to transform an unknown class to JSON.

What I tried :

my scope :

```
var myScope: MyClass = js.native
```

my filter:

```
@injectable("copy")
class CopyFilter extends Filter[Any] {

  override def filter(any: Any): js.Dynamic = {
    val myClass = any.getClass
    fromClassToJsValue[myClass](any)
  }
}
```

my function

```
def fromClassToJsValue[A](value: A)(implicit serializer: Writer[A]): js.Dynamic =
JSON.parse(write(value))
```

In this case my problem is `getClass` which returns `Class[_]` and not `MyClass`

Is there any solution to find `MyClass`? (Or maybe any other solution to derive a type Any?)

Comment: Using `Any` is a bad practice in itself

Comment: it's true but I have to use Any for this case if I don't want to write one filter for each case class...

Comment: Not using `Any` isn't contradictory with generics

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, uPickle isn't designed to deal with that; I don't think any of the other JSON serializers are, either. That sort of Any-friendly serialization is usually based on reflection, which mostly isn't available in the JavaScript environment.

I suspect you do need a Filter per case class, albeit probably a one-liner. (Possibly done as a base trait that you mix into the case classes themselves, but I don't know Angular, so I know don't what the constraints look like.)